# Tracking polyline in graphics view in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

How can polyline and spline be mouse tracked in graphics view using QPainter class in Qt? I have pasted my code. Please check and edit. I am generating a polyline on the click of a button. 
polyline.h

```
#include <QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QDebug>
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "qmath.h"

class polyline: public QObject, public QGraphicsItem
{
     Q_OBJECT
public:
    polyline();
    QRectF boundingRect() const;
    virtual void paint(QPainter * painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem * option, QWidget * widget);
protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *e);
    void mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *e);
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *e);
private:
    int x1, y1, x2, y2, w, h;
    bool mFirstClick;
    bool mSecondClick;
    bool mPaintFlag;
    QVector<QPointF> stuff;
};

#endif // POLYLINE_H
```

polyline.cpp

```
 #include "polyline.h"
#include "QDebug"

polyline::polyline()
{
    mFirstClick = true;
    mSecondClick = false;
    mPaintFlag = false;
}
QRectF polyline::boundingRect() const
{
    // outer most edges
    return QRectF(0,0,800,800);
}

    void polyline::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent* e){
        if(e->button()==Qt::LeftButton) {
            if(mFirstClick){
                x1 = e->pos().x();
                y1 = e->pos().y();
                mFirstClick = false;
                mSecondClick = true;
            }

            else if(!mFirstClick && mSecondClick){
                x2 = e->pos().x();
                y2 = e->pos().y();
                mPaintFlag = true;
                mSecondClick = false;
                update();
            }
        }
        QGraphicsItem::mousePressEvent(e);
        update();
    }
    void polyline:: paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget){
        QRectF rect = boundingRect();
        if(mPaintFlag){
            QPen paintpen(Qt::red);
            paintpen.setWidth(4);

            QPen linepen(Qt::black);
            linepen.setWidth(1);

            QPoint p1;
            p1.setX(x1);
            p1.setY(y1);

            painter->setPen(paintpen);
            painter->drawPoint(p1);

            QPoint p2;
            p2.setX(x2);
            p2.setY(y2);

            painter->setPen(paintpen);
            painter->drawPoint(p2);

            painter->setPen(linepen);
            painter->drawLine(p1, p2);
        }
    }
    void polyline::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *e)
    {

            m_pCurrentLine->setx2(e->x());
            m_pCurrentLine->sety2(e->y());

            m_pCurrentLine->update();

        }
        QGraphicsItem::mouseMoveEvent(e);
    }

    void  polyline::mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *e)
    {
        QGraphicsItem::mouseReleaseEvent(e);
        update();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your own class derived from QGraphicsView and reimplement mouseMoveEvent:

```
void OwnGraphicsView::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    m_pCurrentLine->setX2(event->x());
    m_pCurrentLine->setY2(event->y());

    m_pCurrentLine->update();
}
```

Set Mousetracking for the Widget with the GraphicsView true:

```
setMouseTracking(true);
```

Create a Item derived from QGraphicsItem, for example a class "line" and reimplement paint Method:

```
void line:: paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
```

So everytime the mouseMoveEvent is called, update your lines Coordinates and repaint it.

Hope that helps a little bit.

Comment: Please have a look and reply me.:(

Comment: mouseMoveEvent is in the wrong class. You move over the Graphicsview not over the polyline.

Comment: I write it in the answer. You have to implement it by yourself. This should be a help to point you in the right direction.